# Regex to get digits in a certain format

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have three different types of strings (the dots indicate any alphanumeric character):

1. `Won 1, 2, 3, 4, Lost 5, 6, 7, ...`
2. `5 Wins, ...`
3. `Winner`

How would I create regexes to **match the win numbers only**? I tried something like
`Won (?:(\d)[, ]?)+`, but it only matched the first number, but if I take out "Won", it will match all the numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear one, should be `5` matched in case of `5 Wins,...`?

Comment: There is no number in list item three. What exactly do you want to match? Please do ask a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
>>> foo="Won 1, 2, 3, 4, Lost 5, 6, 7, 8"
>>> [x for x in foo if x.isdigit()]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
>>>
```

That wouldn't work if you want to capture multi-digit numbers, but for the examples you cite, and given that your title references digits, not numbers, it would work.

This would get multi-digit numbers that don't have punctuation attached - you would modify the call to `split()` as necessary to get your desired results given your input:

```
>>> foo="This 23 is not a string with 32 numbers"
>>> [x for x in foo.split() if x.isdigit()]
['23', '32']
```

Comment: It never occurred to me that you could do this without a regex, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use a single regex?  It would be easier to split the string and then get the numbers.

This is a .NET example:

```
// replace everything after Lost with a blank string (would be bad if Lost came before Won)
string text = Regex.Replace( inputString, @"Lost.+", "" );
```

gives:  "Won 1, 2, 3, 4, "

and then

```
Regex.Matches( inputString, @"\d+" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
(?<=Won).*(?=Lost)|\d.*(?=Wins)
```

Tested it in phytex as you gave the python tag for the question.. Fortunately python enables lookafter and lookbehind for regex.